# Build & Deploy Expo app issue when testing with Testflight

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

My I developed and completed the building of a react native application with Expo. I am currently in the process of trying to complete the final build and upload the app to my apple developer account.

With the currently build system, I do the following steps:

1. run `eas build --platform ios`
2. I login to my apple developer account and accept all the settings
3. When the build is complete I download the ipa bundle from the expo.dev link provided
4. I open transporter app and drag the file into the transport app
5. I send the application to my apple developer account
6. I complete the build requirements in the apple developer console
7. I send the beta test to my personal phone and download the build

When I open the build on my phone it crashes.

About a year ago I used `expo build:ios` to build the app and it would always run, build, and deploy perfectly and even run with Testflight and was approved for the app store.

I have no idea why it is crashing on testflight when I try building it with `eas build --platform ios`

Does anyone know waht is causing the app to crash.

Here is my `eas.json` file:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.14.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "...",
        "ascAppId": "...",
        "appleTeamId": "..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my `app.json` file:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Rippe",
    "slug": "Rippe",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/Rippe-Adaptive-Icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/Rippe-App-Splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.rippeinc.Rippe",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.1"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/Rippe-Adaptive-Icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/Rippe-Favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```